# Linux Command redirecting output to file but file is not getting populated

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am issuing a heavy command from bash shell and I have redirected my output to a file as follows

```
 <command> > output.txt
```

But the file does not show any output even though command is running perfectly and I can see the progress through my other tool.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that your command isn't writing to `STDOUT`.

You can use `&>` to redirect both `STDERR` and `STDOUT` to a file.

Also see [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide's IO redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<command> > output.txt 2>&1
```

It seems like your command fail to redirect the output to `STDOUT`, there may be a chance of your output went into `STDERR`. So try to redirect both stdout and stderr to the output file.